# Building Kettle with Ant error: impossible to configure ivy:settings with given file

Tags: ant, pentaho, ivy, kettle

I'm trying to build Kettle5.0 with ant_1.8.2, but I'm getting this following error

```
D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0>ant
Buildfile: D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0\build.xml

antcontrib.download-check:

antcontrib.download:

install-antcontrib:

build-publish-modules:
Duplicated project name in import. Project subfloor defined first in D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0\build-res\subfloor.xml and again in D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0\core\build-re
s\subfloor.xml

antcontrib.download-check:

antcontrib.download:

install-antcontrib:

install-ivy:

resolve-init:

clean-jars:

resolve-default.default:
No ivy:settings found for the default reference 'ivy.instance'.  A default instance will be used
[ivy:resolve] :: Ivy 2.0.0-beta1 - 20071206070608 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
:: loading settings :: file = D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0\core\ivysettings.xml

BUILD FAILED
D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0\build.xml:945: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0\build.xml:950: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0\core\build-res\subfloor.xml:694: impossible to configure ivy:settings with given file: D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0\core\ivysettings.xml :java.text
.ParseException: failed to load settings from file:/D:/IDE/workspace/MyEclipse8.6/Kettle_5.0/core/ivysettings.xml: unable to load properties from null. Tried both as an url and a file, with no success
. File exception: java.lang.NullPointerException. URL exception: java.net.MalformedURLException
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.doParse(XmlSettingsParser.java:96)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.parse(XmlSettingsParser.java:84)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.load(IvySettings.java:369)
        at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.configure(Ivy.java:395)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyAntSettings.createIvyEngine(IvyAntSettings.java:246)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyAntSettings.getConfiguredIvyInstance(IvyAntSettings.java:219)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.getIvyInstance(IvyTask.java:92)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.prepareTask(IvyTask.java:254)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:274)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doSequentialIteration(ForTask.java:259)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doToken(ForTask.java:268)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doTheTasks(ForTask.java:299)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:244)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to load properties from null. Tried both as an url and a file, with no success. File exception: java.lang.NullPointerException. URL exception: jav
a.net.MalformedURLException
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.startElement(XmlSettingsParser.java:230)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.doParse(XmlSettingsParser.java:92)
        ... 68 more

Total time: 0 seconds

D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0>
```

I just check out kettle 5.0 with svn, and just run ant command after that.D:\IDE\workspace\MyEclipse8.6\Kettle_5.0\build.xml is exesting, I googled, but can't help. How can i deal with it~~

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevent error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to load properties from null. Tried both as an url and a file, with no success. File exception: java.lang.NullPointerException. URL exception: jav
a.net.MalformedURLException
```

Are you trying to load an ivy file from a URL? If so could you supply the code? I'm guessing you're doing something like the following construct:

```
<ivy:settings url="${mybuild.settings.url}" />
```

With a ANT property that is unset.